# Apply overflow to single child element, when content is too large

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

I have a column that contains several different elements, like so:

```
<div id="column">
    <h2>Title - can be any length</h2>
    <p id="content">Lorem ipsum, yadda yadda yadda...</p>
    <button>There might be a button here.</button>
    <p>Another paragraph.</p>
    <button>A button here.</button>
</div>
```

I'm using a fluid layout, dependent on window size and, as indicated above, elements will have varying amounts of content and/or may or may not be present.

I want to be able to style the elements so that they all sit one on top of each other, in order at the top (simple enough, obviously)... *except,* in a case where the combined content is taller than the container. In this case, I'd like the `<h2>` to remain at the top, everything from the first `<button>` onwards to all sit at the bottom, with the `<p id="content">` filling the remaining height, with scrollbars.

A purely CSS solution would be great, but I'm using jQuery throughout the site anyway so whatever gets the job done. I'm sure this is quite simple, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/C4hzp/

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** different approach:
put the content in a container with `max-heigth`, that way it can be any height until it reaches the max height: then the scrollbar will appear.

```
<div id="column">
    <h2>Title - can be any length</h2>

    <p class="content">       <!-- Scrollbar starts here -->
        Lorem ipsum, yadda yadda yadda...
    </p>                      <!-- Scrollbar ends here -->

    <button>There might be a button here.</button>

    <p class="content">      <!-- Scrollbar starts here -->
        Another paragraph.
    </p>                     <!-- Scrollbar ends here -->

    <button>A button here.</button>
    <!-- Etc. -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p.content {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4hzp/12/)

Comment: The problem with this is that the dimensions are always going to be different, so specifying a margin won't compensate.

Comment: It's along the right lines. I probably didn't make it clear enough that I need everything that comes after <p id="content"> to always be visible though. The buttons etc should stick to the bottom when the contents are too tall.

Comment: Oh so then just give the `max-height` and the `overflow:auto;` to the `p.content`.  [New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4hzp/12/) and answer updated

Comment: Thanks for the answers, they have helped somewhat - but I think I need to rethink my approach a little as it doesn't seem to be doable with CSS alone.